# Make an array search from multiple values inside a function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to conditionally show fields in WooCommerce checkout depending on the coupon code entered in the cart, The Php I have allows me to search for only one coupon at a time. How can I edit the code to allow to search for multiple coupon codes and show the field if the function finds ANY of the codes?

I have used the existing Php code provided by the Plugnin developer, it works perfectly for one value.

I've also thought about using an 'or' but don't know the syntax well enough to implement.

I also tried to use in_array_any instead of the `in_array` in the code but it produced an error. Probably because I am not familiar with PHP syntax and implemented it wrong.

```
function thwcfe_modify_field_condition_text_field_2($show){
    global $woocommerce;
    $applied_coupons = $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons;
    $show = false;
    if(is_array($applied_coupons) && in_array("will", $applied_coupons)) 
    {
        $show = true;
    }
    return $show;
}
add_filter('thwcfe_show_field_where_did_we_meet', 'thwcfe_modify_field_condition_text_field_2');
```

Comment: Your question would be far better if you had included the array and what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The following using [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) php function, will allow you to search from an array (with multiple values) in an other array (containing multiple values).

**Note:** global `$woocommerce` and `$woocommerce->cart` are outdated and replaced directly by `WC()->cart`.

Here is your revisited code:

```
add_filter('thwcfe_show_field_where_did_we_meet', 'thwcfe_modify_field_condition_text_field_2');
function thwcfe_modify_field_condition_text_field_2( $show = false ){
    // HERE define your coupon codes in the array
    $targeted_coupons = array("will", "other");

    $applied_coupons  = (array) WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons(); // Applied coupons (array)

    return array_intersect($targeted_coupons, $applied_coupons) ? true : false;
}
```

Or as suggested by [@dWinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6487675/dwinder) we cant check the count [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to be bigger than 0 like:

```
return count( array_intersect($targeted_coupons, $applied_coupons) ) > 0 ? true : false;
```

It will work too.

Comment: Notice the `array_intersect` return array - PHP will treat empty array as false - that why the `if` statement works. Better practice will be to check `count` of `array_intersect` response bigger then 0

Comment: @dWinder I know, but this works perfectly on this kind of cases. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: @dWinder I have added your suggestion… Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for clarity but you could use a switch statement here?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Depends on if you need it to be dynamic or you're looking to just hardcode some vouchers but the below should work for you (not tested, just from looking at the question)

```
function thwcfe_modify_field_condition_text_field_2($show){
    global $woocommerce;
    $applied_coupons = $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons;
    $show = false;
    if(is_array($applied_coupons)) {
        switch(true) {
          case(in_array("will", $applied_coupons) :
             return $show = true;
          case(in_array("another_coupon", $applied_coupons) :
             return $show = true;
          default:
             return $show;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no benefit to this more verbose syntax.  Loic's solution is the way to go.

Comment: I agree the above answer is better. However the question hadn't been answered when I left this reply and I was simply trying to help